# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bounds'

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas

I have the following geodataframes, corresponding to a regular grid:

```
        id   grid_id    geometry
0       48         0    (POLYGON ((2.052457758079306 41.42493869117656...
1       49         1    (POLYGON ((2.052470852112577 41.42403805731954...
2       215        2    (POLYGON ((2.053641274433816 41.42584917461342...
3       216        3    (POLYGON ((2.053654352531821 41.42494854059127...
4       217        4    (POLYGON ((2.053667430035439 41.42404790642426...
```

and a points geodataframe:

```
    id_act  geometry
0   4001    POINT (2.183026563657264 41.37459702541483)
1   4003    POINT (2.183012216695291 41.37471411724238)
2   4003    POINT (2.183128113845906 41.37472901746361)
3   3002    POINT (2.182820482338962 41.37482095671629)
4   4003    POINT (2.182945418252172 41.37482221760939)
```

I'm merging the two dataframes through a spatial join:

```
BCN_id_grid = gpd.sjoin(gdf, grid, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

but it returns the following `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bounds'
```

the point is that when I call the function:

```
grid.bounds
```

it yields:

```
        minx         miny       maxx         maxy
0   2.052458    41.424038   2.053667    41.424949
1   2.052471    41.423137   2.053681    41.424048
2   2.053641    41.424949   2.054851    41.425859
3   2.053654    41.424048   2.054864    41.424958
4   2.053667    41.423147   2.054877    41.424058
5   2.053681    41.422247   2.054890    41.423157
```

calling both `type(gdf.geomtry[0])` or `type(grid.geomtry[0])` gives:

```
shapely.geometry.point.Point
shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon
```

respectively.

Does anyone know where is the mistake?

Comment: Are you sure the geometries intersect? When I get None type returned it is usually because my geometry does not intersect, is there a method to check if the intersection exists before you join?

Comment: The files come from a `csv` file and a `geojson` file that apparently intersect in QGIS 3.4 environment. I've converted the first file several times from `csv` to `geojson` trying to fix the error without success. I chnged the `crs` already...

Comment: maybe do an "outer" join and see what comes out. it looks to me that your point is not within the polygon, I can't see all coords for the polygon but the ones I see all have longitude around 2.05 and your point longitude is 2.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved trying `points.bounds` that yields the same attribute error message:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bounds'`

So that means that the mistake was in the points geodataframe.

I ran the following script to slice the valid geometries:

`points_fix = points.loc[points.is_valid]`

It discards just about 1,000 points out of the original geodataframe, composed by more than 78,000 features, which works statistically for my purpose.